# Django model relationship best solution

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

`Basket` and a `Fruit`

A `Basket` can have multiple `Fruit` objects in them, and a `Fruit` belongs to a single `Basket`. Each `Fruit` can be ordered manually so that when they're listed, they show the order in which they were saved. So far so good.

```
class Basket (models.Model):
    # A fruit basket
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_virtual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # This is just a badly constructed example of how a list
    # of basket primary keys are saved when creating the virtual basket
    # This is only for demonstration purposes to solve the overall modelling issue
    virtual_baskets = models.TextField(null=True)

class Fruit (models.Model):
    # The basket this fruit belongs to
    basket = models.ForeignKey("Basket", related_name="fruits", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Manually sorted order
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

However, there's a flag on the `Basket` called `is_virtual` which allows users to create virtual combo-Baskets out of existing, real Baskets, in which you end up breaking the rules slightly: a virtual basket can in fact combine two existing `Baskets` and thus `Fruit`s from two baskets. I need to be able to allow users to manually sort and re-order the the `Fruit`s in these baskets without overwriting the ordering in their original baskets.

As an example:

`Basket A` contains, in order: Apple, Banana

`Basket B` contains, in order: Orange, Grapes

I now wish to create a virtual `Basket C` that would show the fruits from both A and B like so:

Apple, Grapes, Banana, Orange

A note to bear: a virtual basket is simply combining results from various other baskets. To the user it's still a valid basket they should be able to re-order fruits in.

How do I model this ordering relationship? I am considering adding a new model:

```
class FruitAppearance (models.Model):
    # The basket this appearance is tied to
    basket = models.ForeignKey("Basket", related_name="manually_sorted_fruits", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # The fruit it represents
    fruit = models.ForeignKey("Fruit", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Order
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Am I thinking it right? Is there a better way? Should I be using a ManyToManyField in one of the existing `Fruit` and `Basket` models?

Comment: Fruit belongs to a single Basket, no matter if its virtual or not ?

Comment: Correct, it only ever belongs to a single real basket  but can be presented in different ways in virtual baskets

Comment: Virtual baskets can be saved as well of course and the manual fruit ordering should persist with it

Comment: Is it possible to have virtual_basket_a -> apple , virtual_basket_b -> apple, my_basket -> apple ?

Comment: Essentially if you create a virtual basket, it will always be on fruits that already belong to a real basket. So all fruits from the real basket will always show. The only added feature here is that the user is able to sort the display order of each fruit in the virtual baskets they create.

Comment: When they click on a basket, they would see the original ordering they kept in that basket. Similarly when they click a virtual combo basket, they see the modified order they saved in that. To the user a virtual basket is still a basket, but only a combo they created manually out of a list of baskets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fruits = models.ManyToMany("Fruit", through="FruitBasket")
    ...

class Fruit(models.Model):
    ...

class FruitBasket(models.Model:
    basket = models.ForeignKey("Basket", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fruit = models.ForeignKey("Fruit", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

This way you will have some data redundancy but may be able to set different order numbers for fruits in every basket.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm wondering, FruitBasket here is exactly the same as the FruitAppearance model class I created. The only difference I see is the added redundancy (as you said) in Basket.. will not having that there make a difference?

Comment: Yup, the fruit redundancy is exactly what allows you to set different order values for a single fruit in different baskets (e.g. Lemon has order level 1 in Basket A but order level 4 in Basket B). Without this redundancy you would only be able to set a fixed order level for a fruit.

Comment: I see.. I suppose at the db model level the class alone creates the desired intermediate table, but then the 'fruits' property accessible from the Bucket is what will programmatically allow us to access / set those properties. Of course. Thank you, I think that's unfortunate but the only reasonable addition to the model to get it to work!

Comment: Although come to think of it, this may not work. VirtualBucket.fruits will return None since it doesn't physically own any tasks, at runtime we use a complex set of filters to find and combine results from various buckets. The virtual bucket thus serves no other purpose than a placeholder with meta data but one that is being treated as a normal bucket so it can appear normally in the list of available buckets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following.
Separate your models Basket and Virtual Basket, as a result remove the field virtual.

So each Fruit can belong to one Basket (ForeignKey), but at the same time to multiple Virtual Baskets (ManyToManyField). In the manytomany field use the parameter throught and include another model which will store only the order of the fruit for that specific virtual basket.

```
class Fruit (models.Model):
    # The basket this fruit belongs to
    basket = models.ForeignKey("Basket", related_name="fruits", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    virtual_basket = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit, through='FruitOrdering')

    # Manually sorted order
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: That isn't a viable solution sadly. The fruit will always only exist and be owned by the actual real basket created. Since the above is a simple example of what the real app is trying to do, the real app creates complex search filters and creates Smart Lists out of existing lists of stuff. Think of a Contacts app where contacts come from various accounts / providers, and we create virtual lists out of them. Each provider orders the contacts, which we need to then allow re-ordering of in our smart list representations.